# start IntentService with root privileges

Tags: android, permissions, android-intentservice

I have Android device with root. When I use permission INJECT_EVENTS from Activity itself it's OK. But I started IntentService from activity and inside IntentService I want to use the permission, but it gives message that service requires INJECT_EVENTS permission. What am I doing wrong? How can I start IntentService with same priveleges as the application itself?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, backgroundService.class);
    startService(intent);
    ........
```